# Google Cloud Platform Log Viewer logs truncate jsonPayload message for error log

Tags: spring-boot, google-cloud-platform, slf4j, google-cloud-pubsub, google-cloud-logging

The logs I'm viewing in the Log Viewer are truncating the "message" part of the payload, but the "exception" part of the payload doesn't have a limit and shows the entire stacktrace. These logs are for exceptions caught in my service running in Google Cloud.

The service is built with Spring Boot using SLF4J as a logger factory. I use SLF4J's LoggerFactory to create a logger based on the class where it's invoked and when an exception is caught, I log using the logger's `error("Exception thrown processing this message: ${message.data}", exception)` where `message` is of type com.google.pubsub.v1.PubsubMessage and `exception` is a Throwable of type java.lang.Exception.

Comment: How did you noticed the truncation?Have you tried with a different browser or by using incognito mode? This to verify that the cache of the browser is not causing this truncation.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.
The only way is to jump to Logs Explore and watch the log.

[image]

[image]